# recoger valor option php

Tags: php, select

tengo un código similar a este:

```
 echo "<select name='$nombre' id='$id'>";
 echo "<option value='0'>Seleccione opcion</option>";
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $id= $row[$campo_valor];
     $texto= $row[$campo_visual];
     $sel="";

     if ($default==$id){
         $sel="Selected";
     }
     echo "\n <option value='$id' $sel>$texto</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";
```

Me gustaría saber cómo recoger el valor del option (value="$id"), ya que recogiendo el valor del select, el resultado es 0.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Buenas tardes, tengo un código similar a este:

echo "<select name='$nombre' id='$id'>";
 echo "<option value='0'>Seleccione opcion</option>";
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $id= $row[$campo_valor];
 $texto= $row[$campo_visual];
 $sel="";
 if ($default==$id){
 $sel="Selected";
 }
 echo "\n <option value='$id' $sel>$texto</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";

Me gustaría saber cómo recoger el valor del option (value="$id"), ya que recogiendo el valor del select, el resultado es 0.

Muchas gracias

Comment: este es el código que quería poner, pero no me lo cogía bien.muchas gracias

Comment: Ya lo conseguí esta mañana. Muchas gracias a todos por vuestras aportaciones y vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Sara, lee [answer] y completa el [tour]. No pongas un mensaje de agradecimiento en las respuestas, en su lugar, marca como aceptada y/o vota positivo por las respuestas que te sirvieron para solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

ahi tienes un ejemplo , no entiendo tu codigo

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<label class="control-label">Puesto</label>
<select class="form-control requeridoPuesto input-sm selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="puesto" id="puesto">
<option>Seleccione</option>
<?php 
foreach ($puestos as $puesto){
?>                            
<option if($puesto['puesto']=='programador'){ echo 'selected';} value="<?php echo $puesto['idPuesto']?>"><?php echo $puesto['nombre']?></option>
<?php
}
?> 
</select> 
</div>
```

recoger valor del select

```
$puesto= $_POST["puesto"];
```

Comment: el código lo he puesto más abajo, es que me lo ha publicado mal el foro, gracias

Comment: quieres imprimir o recoger el value ?

Comment: recoger el value, si recojo el select, el valor siempre va a ser 0 con ese tipo de código

Comment: como va hacer siempre 0 xddd si la tabla de ejemplo es de puestos debes tener algo haci 1 administrador 2 programador 3 contador los numeros son los Id que tu estas trayendo y los otros son el nombre del puesto ¿explicame por que va hacer siempre 0?

Comment: Estas recogiendo el valor con php o javascript??

Comment: con PHP, también lo intenté con javascript

Comment: Cómo estas declarando el form?

Answer (score 0):

Por ejemplo, dado este select:

```
<select id='test'>
    <option selected value="A">B</option>
</select>
```

Entonces, si quieres A es:

```
alert(document.getElementById("test").value);
```

Y si quieres B es:

```
alert(document.getElementById("test").text);
```

Es decir, value retorna el valor del option meintras que text el texto del mismo.

Comment: voy a probar así, quería evitar javascript,jeje. muchas gracias

Comment: Entonces creo que es así: $selectOption = $_POST['NAME DEL SELECT']; si envías por POST el form a PHP

Comment: Sí, si eso es lo que he hecho, pero con este tipo de código me da 0, no sé cómo puedo recoger el valor <option value='$id' $sel>$texto</option>

Comment: Tal vez si publicas el código de tu formulario, puede que el fallo esté ahí.

Answer (score 0):

Lo siento por no poner la respuesta, es que era una tontería lo que me pasaba. No me recogía el "name" del  porque el form no se cerraba en el lugar que debía, me di cuenta cuando utilicé inspeccionar elemento.